# Format date in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string used to display the datetime, like: `Mon, dd Dec YYYY hh:mm:ss`.

I want to display it like this: `dd Dec YYYY`. Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

```
// create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
```

See also:

> [Custom Date and Time Format Strings - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

if you only have the string, just split the string to an array, and concatenate the parts you want in another order

```
String str = "Mon, dd Dec YYYY hh:mm:ss";
String[] strArr = str.Split(" ");
str = strArr[2] + " " + strArr[3];
```

If the date can change, then do what SLaks posted in his answer

Comment: Since there's only one parameter, you should call `DateTime.ToString`.

Comment: He doesn't have a datetime, he has a string

Comment: the array is not a good idea, what if the date format changes? say it becomes 2010 Jan 28?

Comment: **Do NOT do this**. it will result in brittle code that will unexpectedly return meaningless data if the date format changes.  Instead, you should parse the string into a DateTime so that you get an error instead of data corruption if the format changes.

Comment: Is it necessary to do that even tho he doesn't state it can change?, also is splitting faster or slower than creating a new date object?

Answer (score 3):

You can call the formatting methods on the DateTime class

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("Mon, 28 Dec 2009 04:34:17", "ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string output = time.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) is a list of options for the format strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(myStringContainingDate);

myDateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You could just use Substring, since it's always going to be 11 characters, starting at position 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(yourDateString);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd MMM YYYY"));
```

Full spec [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

I believe the correct string would be dd MMM yyyy

Answer (score 0):

In `C# 6.0` you can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/csharp-six#String-Interpolation) in order to display formatted dates.

```
DateTime fullDate = DateTime.Parse("Sat, 17 JUL 2021 02:22:22");
string date = $"{fullDate: dd MMM yyyy}";
```