# DateTime format in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format date in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151744/format-date-in-c)

I want to display the date in the format`May 16, 2011`. I have used format `String.Format("{0:D}"` by which i got the output like `Monday, May 16, 2011` . 
So please any one tell me how i will be able to show date time in the following format`May 16, 2011`
Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer tells you everything you need to know about formatting dates, follow the links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151744/format-date-in-c/2151752#2151752

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"{0:MMMM d, yyyy}"
```

Here is the documentation.

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: thanks sir i got what i want thank once again

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
String.Format("{0:MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);
```

This should to the trick?

EDIT: Here are some handy examples! http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", someDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use D for a date format the format will be taken from the Regional settings in the control panel of the machine.  You could change the date format of the machine the software is running on.  (Or hand code a format).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a [Standard Date and Time Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) that matches your desired format, so you need to construct a [Custom Date and Time Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

This should do the trick:

```
string.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", value)
```

Or alternatively

```
value.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

- MMMM - The full name of the month, e.g. June (en-US)
- dd - The day of the month, from 01 through 31
- yyyy - The year as a four-digit number.