# Parse Polish Date string into DateTime

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have the following string "24.04.2018 00:00:00". I want to get DateTime object from that string in following format: MM/dd/yyyy

I tried following:

```
 string input = "24.04.2018 00:00:00";

 DateTime d;

 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
 {
     //do something
 }
```

but it did not succeed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format date in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151744/format-date-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The fundametal error with your attempt is that you seem to be thinking you can parse a DateTime into a specific format. That's completely wrong. You need to parse your input to turn it into a DateTime and that DateTime can be formatted as a string.

Comment: that is correct, I misunderstood parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` doesn't have format itself, but you can create formatted string from the `DateTime` by using `ToString(format)` method.

You need first convert string to the `DateTime` and then convert it to string of required format.

```
var input = "24.04.2018 00:00:00";

var output = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                     .ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy");
```

Comment: Downvoters, can you explain where is mistake in the answer? will be glad to fix it or remove an answer.

Comment: Currently your answer is almost correct but OP wanted DateTime, not a string.Title says *"Parse Polish Date string into DateTime"*. More over you have posted many different versions for your solution. Perhaps downvoters only read previous versions that didn't even compile.

Comment: output is still  "04.24.2018", why?

Comment: @iantukic, you need escape delimiters, check updated answer

Comment: @Fabio why would you need to escape `/` characters?

Comment: @phuzi because of polish culture

Comment: @iantukic AFAIK C# doesn't treat `/` as a special character and it shouldn't need escaping

Comment: @phuzi well in polish culture it needs escaping

Comment: I would use `TryParse` instead of `ParseExact` with use of `new CultureInfo("pl")` to support all Poland date time formats not only the specific provided case (eg. 24.04.2018, 24.4.2018 and so on)

Answer (score -1):

The string is in the format `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss` you'll need to use that exact format for ParseExact. Then you can output it in whatever format you like

```
string input = "24.04.2018 00:00:00";

DateTime d;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
{
    var formattedDate = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

[Demo on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ne3q1t)

Comment: if statement doesn't succeed, why?