# How to spell out Month using ToShortDateString?

Tags: c#, date, formatting

Right now I have something like this

```
string formatted_string =  DateTime.Parse(sting_date).Trim()).ToShortDateString();
```

this gives me `10/07/2019`

How can I take that and get back `October 07, 2019`?

Comment: You can't. There are different date formats than the short date format. Use one of them instead (like LongDateFormat, which returns that specific format).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format date in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151744/format-date-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you literally mean that you want to use that exact code and get back the string you requested, the only way would be to first alter the current culture settings.

```
CultureInfo customCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
customCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```

When you call `.ToShortDateString()` on a `DateTime`, it uses the `ShortDatePattern` from the `DateTimeFormat` of the current culture.  Thus by altering the current culture to be a custom culture, your `.ToShortDateString()` call can use a custom format.

This is really a stretch though.  It's much easier just to ask for that format to begin with using `.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")`